# C# List-like class constructor

Tags: c#, types

I'm making a Tree class that will contain nodes etc. I want to be able to define my Tree's in a similar way to constructing a list, E.g; `Tree<*dataType*> = new Tree<*datatype*>();` This will allow me to store and grab each of those datatypes from the nodes contained within.

My Tree structure will contain a list of nodes, each being constructed in a similar way (`Node<*datatype*>`) these will contain an instance of a type, e.g Integer. This type will be common to the tree and all nodes contained within.

I've Googled around but have not been able to find anything.

How can i accomplish this if at all possible?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx

Comment: I sort of have a vague idea what you might be after, but it would help if you could demonstrate the requirement, and what code you already have for this `Tree` class. Generics may provide some answer, but it sounds like you want to query the `Tree` for nodes of a given type, so I am confused why you want to *create* a `Tree` to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to find the answer for this after all.

[Generic Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx)

This allowed me to write this basic class which will completely (eventually) fulfill my requirements.

```
class Tree<T>
{
    Node<T> PrimaryNode;

    public void SetPrimaryNode(T obj){
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>();
        node.setObject(obj);
        this.PrimaryNode = node;
    }

    public void SetPrimaryNode(Node<T> node)
    {
        this.PrimaryNode = node;
    }

    public Node<T> GetPrimaryNode()
    {
        return PrimaryNode;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 Kudos for trying to find the answer yourself anyway, and reporting it back here as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

You should make Tree Inhert from List like this:

```
public class Tree<T> : List<T> where T : class
{
  ...
}
```

Edit: You could instead of List also use ICollection then you ll have to write all the logic yourself for .Add .Remove etc

Comment: I'll be writing the logic for all of that myself due to the very specific requirements i need for it to do! I'll have a look into ICollection, looks like it may be handy.